# How to plot an ellipsoid in MATLAB knowing eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Tags: matlab

Using

```
[V,D]=eig(Pmatrix)
```

I get

```
V=
 0.7107  0.6581  -0.2486
-0.6849  0.7280  -0.0306
-0.1608  -0.1920  -0.9681

D=
103.2955           0              0
       0    127.9054              0
       0           0       135.6728
```

where, as I understand it, the first column of V is the eigenvector associated with the first eigenvalue given for D (=103.2955).  The second column of V is associated with 2nd value of D (=127.9054), the third column of V associated with 3rd value of D (=135.6728).

With these I would like to generate a surface of an ellipsoid (i.e. a 3D plot).  So this is my question, how might I do that using matlab?

The eigenvectors I calculated should be orthogonal and represent the directions of the axes of the ellipsoid (and I note that these axes are not collinear with the axes of my right-handed Cartesian x, y, z (z-upward) coordinate system, thus the ellipsoid is rotated at some angle(s) to my coordinate system); the lengths of the semi-axes of the ellipsoid are computed from the eigenvalues.